# What is the Statistical probability below?

Tags: probability

I Have been strugling with this problem, Can anyone help?

Peace Health Hospital performs approximately 630 open heart procedures per year. On average about 20% of those procedures require valvular repairs that would benefit from having a robot. What is the probability that Peace Health Hospital will serve 70 patients or more per year who will require a valvular repair and benefit from the robot?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be the number who would benefit. Then $X$ has binomial distribution, $n=630$, $p=0.2$. It follows that $X$ has mean $np=126$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{np(1-p)}\approx 10.04$.

Using the norml approximation to the binomial, we find that the required probability is approximately equal to the probability that 
$$Z\gt \frac{70-126}{10.04},$$
where $Z$ is standard normal.

Since $\frac{70-126}{10.04}\lt -5.5$, this is probability is $1$ for all practical (and impractical) purposes.